# Display tagged items in lists sorted by tags

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, tags, relationship

I have tasks that have tags in this format:

```
Array 
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
      (
         [task_id] => 10,
         [task_text] => Mow and fertilize,
         [tags] => Array
            (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 1,
                     [tag_text] => House,
                     [tt_tag_id] => 1, //from relational table, tt = task_tag
                     [tt_task_id] => 10,
                     [tt_id] => 20, //auto id from relational table
                     [tt_order] => 0
                  ),
               [1] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 2,
                     [tag_text] => Yard,
                     [task_tag_id] => 2, 
                     [task_task_id] => 10,
                     [tt_id] => 21,
                     [tt_order] => 1
                  )
               [2] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 5,
                     [tag_text] => Lawn,
                     [task_tag_id] => 5, 
                     [task_task_id] => 10,
                     [tt_id] => 22,
                     [tt_order] => 2
                  )
             )
       )
   [1] => stdClass Object
      (
         [task_id] => 11,
         [task_text] => Unclog the sink drain,
         [tags] => Array
            (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 1,
                     [tag_text] => House,
                     [task_tag_id] => 1, 
                     [task_task_id] => 11
                     [tt_id] => 30,
                     [tt_order] => 0
                  ),
               [1] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 3,
                     [tag_text] => Kitchen,
                     [task_tag_id] => 3, 
                     [task_task_id] => 11,
                     [tt_id] => 31,
                     [tt_order] => 1
                  )
             )
       )
   [2] => stdClass Object
      (
         [task_id] => 12,
         [task_text] => Purchase new microwave,
         [tags] => Array
            (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 4,
                     [tag_text] => Apartment 1,
                     [task_tag_id] => 4, 
                     [task_task_id] => 12
                     [tt_id] => 40,
                     [tt_order] => 0
                  ),
               [1] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 3,
                     [tag_text] => Kitchen,
                     [task_tag_id] => 3, 
                     [task_task_id] => 12,
                     [tt_id] => 41,
                     [tt_order] => 1
                  )
             )
       )
)
```

I want to be able to sort the tasks by the tags like this:

```
Array 
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
      (
         [tag_id] => 1,
         [task_text] => House,
         [child_tags] => Array
            (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 2,
                     [tag_text] => Yard,
                     [task_tag_id] => 2, 
                     [task_task_id] => 10,
                     [tt_id] => 21,
                     [child_tags] => Array
                        (
                           [1] => stdClass Object
                              (
                                  [tag_id] => 5,
                                  [tag_text] => Lawn,
                                  [task_tag_id] => 5, 
                                  [task_task_id] => 10,
                                  [tt_id] => 22,
                                  [task_id] => 10,
                                  [task_text] => Mow and fertilize
                              )
                        ),
               [1] => stdClass Object
                 (
                    [tag_id] => 3,
                    [tag_text] => Kitchen,
                    [task_tag_id] => 3, 
                    [task_task_id] => 11,
                    [tt_id] => 31,
                    [task_id] => 11,
                    [task_text] => Unclog the sink drain,
                 )
             )
       )
 [1] => stdClass Object
      (
         [tag_id] => 4,
         [tag_text] => Apartment 1,
         [child_tags] => Array
            (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                     [tag_id] => 2,
                     [tag_text] => Kitchen,
                     [task_tag_id] => 2, 
                     [task_task_id] => 10,
                     [tt_id] => 21,
                     [task_id] => 12,
                     [task_text] => Purchase new microwave
                  )
            )
       )
)
```

Ultimately what I am shooting for is:

```
<ul>
   <lh>House</lh>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <lh>Kitchen</lh>
         <li>Unclog the sink drain</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <lh>Yard</lh>
          <li>
             <ul>
               <lh>Lawn</lh>
               <li>Mow and fertilize</li>
             </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <lh>Apartment 1</lh>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <lh>Kitchen</lh>
         <li>Purchase new microwave</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The database is exactly how you imagine. A task table and a tag table with a n2n relational table.

There doesn't appear to be a simple way to loop through the tasks and tags to sort them in this manner. Should I try different approach? Is this silly?

Comment: I don't see any parent/child references for tags, so how are you supposed to get them in a hierarchy like that? Also, the `<lh>` item is not in the HTML spec, so avoid it.

Comment: At first I was trying to order by the tt_id which isn't really what that is for..so I added a tt_order column, this is the order in which the tags are associated with the task. I might be getting close to my own solution after adding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can construct your array in a hierarchical structure (i.e. pulling all of your tags and assigning the tasks as a nested array for each tag), resembling an unsorted version of your final structure, you could try two recursive loops:

1. Take the Level 1 items, sort() this
2. For each of the Level 1 items, print it out and sort the Level 2
3. Repeat until down to the lowest level

Comment: I did end up using a recursive function that operates as you described.